# Self-adjoint operator and eigenbasis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let us assume that we have a self-adjoint operator $A: D(A) \subset L^2 \rightarrow L^2$ and we know that $A$ has a purely discrete spectrum and the eigenvalues of $A$ are simple. Does that mean that there is an eigenbasis $(b_n)$ such that $(b_n)$ is an ONB of $L^2$?

Could anybody explain, if this holds, where this actually follows from?

Comment: well I guess that otherwise $A$ cannot be self-adjoint.

Comment: The statement is true. Consult any standard text on unbounded self-adjoint operators for a proof. The book by Konrad Schmüdgen titled 'Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space' has this as Proposition 5.12.

Comment: You can reduce the problem to a bounded normal operator by considering $$T=\frac{A-i}{A+i}.$$ Or even $T=(1+A^2)^{-1}A$, which is bounded self-adjoint and with simple eigenvlaues as well.

Comment: When you say "purely discrete spectrum," do you mean that the distance from $\lambda \in\sigma(A)$ to $\sigma(A)\setminus\{\lambda\}$ is strictly positive? If so, then $(A-\mu I)^{-1}$ is a compact selfadjoint operator for any $\mu \in\mathbb{R}\setminus\sigma(A)$.

Comment: @T.A.E. I meant that the continuous spectrum is empty

Answer (score 1):

There is a potential problem with this. You can construct a selfadjoint operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $X$ with $\sigma(A)=[0,1]$ such that every point in the spectrum is in the point spectrum. The problems is this: once you remove the discrete space, you can still be left with an operator with only continuous spectrum. The definition of point spectrum does not preclude the possibility of continuous spectrum being mixed in. Once a $\lambda$ is tainted by calling is an element of the point spectrum, there are no further qualifiers for it. So, hiding beneath of this can be continuous spectrum, even though--technically speaking--$\sigma(A)=\sigma_{p}(A)$.

For example, Let $H=L^{2}_{\mu}[0,1]$ where $\mu$ is counting measure, and let $K=L^{2}_{m}[0,1]$ where $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Define $A : H \times K \rightarrow H\times K$ by
$$
                  A\langle f,g \rangle = \langle xf(x), xg(x)\rangle.
$$
For every $\lambda\in[0,1]$, the function $\delta_{\lambda}(x)\in H$ which is $0$ except at $\lambda$, where it is $1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Therefore,
$$
                    A\langle \delta_{\lambda},0\rangle = \lambda \langle \delta_{\lambda},0\rangle
$$
That means every $\lambda\in[0,1]$ is in the point spectrum of $A$. The eigenvectors
$\{ \langle \delta_{\lambda},0\rangle \}_{\lambda\in[0,1]}$ form an orthonormal basis of the subspace $H\times\{0\}\subset H\times K$. And the restriction of $A$ to orthogonal complement of this space has only continuous spectrum. So $A$ does not have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, even though it has only 'discrete' spectrum.